# How to do select all and unselect all of a WPF datagrid on a button click using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

How can I select all rows/unselect all rows of a WPF datagrid on a button click without messing up the MVVM pattern ?

Currently I doing something like this:

## XAML

```
<Button Command="{Binding SelButtonClicked}" .../>
```

and in the Mainviewmodel

```
public RelayCommand SelButtonClicked { get; set; }
...
Public Mainviewmodel()
{
  SelButtonClicked = new RelayCommand(SelUnsel);
}
...
public void SelUnsel(object param)
        {
            var win = Application.Current.Windows
                .Cast<Window>()
                .FirstOrDefault(window => window is MainWindow) as MainWindow;
            
            if (win.myGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                win.myGrid.UnselectAll();
            }
            else
            {
                win.myGrid.SelectAll();
            }
        }
```

But I'm pretty sure it is not the MVVM way ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding SelButtonClicked}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=dataGrid}"
        .../>
```

```cs
        private void SelUnsel(object param)
        {
            IList list = (IList) param;
            list.Clear();
        }
```

> how do I do the opposite i.e. select all ?

```cs
        private void SelAll(object param)
        {
            IList list = (IList) param;
            foreach(var item in SomeItemCollection)
                list.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: I think it should be `param` and not `parameter` in the method, also it unselects when rows as selected by how do I do the opposite i.e. select all ?

Comment: @TamalBanerjee , This is my carelessness. I made a mistake. I've made corrections to the sample code.

Comment: @TamalBanerjee , I added an example with the implementation of selecting all elements from some ViewModel collection.

Comment: Is `SomeItemCollection` supposed to be the Itemsource of the datagrid ? In my case it an `ICollectionView`...I'm a bit confused ...Also I want to do the select all and dis select all using the same button

Comment: also my `SelectionMode="Extended"`

Comment: You correctly guessed.
If the collection is not implemented at the ViewModel level, then, accordingly, the traversal of this collection must be done at the same level at which this collection is declared.
Or pass both collections to the command.
That is, the command is an abstraction and for its operation it is necessary to transfer all the data to it.
You can pass either through a parameter, or when creating a command (this happens when setting a ViewModel instance method).
In this case, you need a collection to add to, and a collection of whose elements to add.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is my final implementation using @EldHasp 's shown method.

```xml
    <Button Command="{Binding SelButtonClicked}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=dataGrid}"
            .../>
```

```cs
    public void SelUnsel(object param)
    {
                IList list = (IList) param;
                
                if (list.Count > 0)
                {
                    list.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach(var item in dgItemSource)
                        list.Add(item);
                }
    }
```